# Wait loading icon disappear before action

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

right now i'm using testcafe for automation, right now i have problem that sometime the loading of website will very high, so have idea that in website have loading icon, so have solution that will wait until the loading icon disappear, so we don't need use hard wait
So have anyone use it or have any experience with that, please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the target element to finish loading. It allows you to avoid using the `wait` action.

```js
test('test', async t => {
    const loadingIcon = Selector('#loading-icon');
 
    await t
        .expect(loadingIcon.visible).ok() // loading icon is appeared
        .expect(loadingIcon.visible).notOk(); // loading icon is disappeared
});
```